# MySQL INSERT shows more affected rows than affected

Tags: mysql

Consider the following three queries.

The first one can only return a single row as `bids_buy.id` is the primary key.

The second one shows an existing record in `entities_has_documents` for primary key `3099541982-2536988132`, and the third one doesn't execute due to that existing record.

The forth one does execute as expected, but shows two affected rows.

Why does it show two affected rows, and not just one associated with primary key `3099541982-2536988132`?

```
mysql> SELECT bb.bids_sell_id, 2536988132,"pub_bids", NOW(),506836355 FROM bids_buy bb WHERE bb.id=2453409798;
+--------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| bids_sell_id | 2536988132 | pub_bids | NOW()               | 506836355 |
+--------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+
|   3099541982 | 2536988132 | pub_bids | 2016-04-16 08:19:13 | 506836355 |
+--------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM entities_has_documents;
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| entities_id | documents_id | type     | date_added          | date_removed | added_by  | removed_by | purged_by | date_purged |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  2453409798 |   2536988132 | pub_bids | 2016-04-16 08:07:13 | NULL         | 506836355 |       NULL |      NULL | NULL        |
|  3099541982 |   2536988132 | pub_bids | 2016-04-16 08:18:53 | NULL         | 506836355 |       NULL |      NULL | NULL        |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO entities_has_documents(entities_id,documents_id,type,date_added,added_by)
    -> SELECT bb.bids_sell_id, 2536988132,"pub_bids", NOW(),506836355 FROM bids_buy bb WHERE bb.id=2453409798;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3099541982-2536988132' for key 'PRIMARY'

mysql> INSERT INTO entities_has_documents(entities_id,documents_id,type,date_added,added_by)
    -> SELECT bb.bids_sell_id, 2536988132,"pub_bids", NOW(),506836355 FROM bids_buy bb WHERE bb.id=2453409798
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type="pub_bids", added_by=506836355, date_added=NOW(), removed_by=NULL, date_removed=NULL;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> EXPLAIN bids_buy;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| bids_sell_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| stage_buy_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN entities_has_documents;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entities_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| documents_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type         | varchar(16)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| date_added   | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date_removed | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| added_by     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| removed_by   | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| purged_by    | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| date_purged  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

**EDIT**

Per http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

So, am I just seeing the number or rows returned from my SELECT statement, and not the number or rows affected by my INSERT?  Why would MySQL do such a thing?

**EDIT DONE**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is due to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` modifier as the [MYSQL Reference Manual 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) as well as [MySQL Reference Manual 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) says

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed. The affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set to its current values.”.

In your case you already had a row with primary key value `3099541982-2536988132`. Hence the MySQL lets you know that you are trying to insert a row with duplicate Primary or Unique key by indicating 2 rows affected. As the manual also say that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` leads to the sequence of `INSERT` than `UPDATE` update command in case of duplicate key whereas it executes only the `INSERT` command in case the key is not present.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Also see this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Wow, so you are saying that `rows affected` has nothing to do with the quantity of rows affected?  I totally agree with you in that the documentation seems to say so, but never expected so.

Comment: Yes you are right it is mysql semantics to let the user know that what type of command you are using and what it will lead to in terms of number of operations etc. You can just try truncate command it deletes all the rows in the table but it returns number of rows affected as 0 because truncate is DDL command and it leads to the sequence of DROP and CREATE TABLE command. Hence number of rows affected is 0 as per the semantics of DDL command.

Comment: Thank you geeksal,  Great answer, and definitely learned something today.

Comment: The rows **affected** count is correct.  1 row inserted, because your insert didn't fail, and 1 row updated because of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` finding a duplicate row.  It just happens to be the same row.  To always report "1" would leave you not knowing whether the row already existed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot One row affected twice != two rows affected. This mechanic is completely counterintuitive and renders the affected row count utterly useless if you're upserting multiple rows.